# How does this differential equation define an oscillation from a to b?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, elliptic-functions, elliptic-equations

The differential equation reads:
$$
\dot{y}^2+(y^2-a^2)(y^2-b^2)=0
$$

where $a,b\in \mathcal{R}$ and $a<b$.

It is claimed that this differential equation defines an oscillation from $a$ to $b$.

So I did the research: differentiate w.r.t. $x$. Then I get:

$$
\ddot{y}= (a^2+b^2)y-2y^3
$$

Then I looked up in [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html), compared with equation(20), I get $k=\sqrt{2-(a^2+b^2)}$.

So I plot the graph using JacobiCN[x,k] in mathematica, it seems not right.

For example:[image]

I know we need the initial value to get the behavior, since the initial condition is not clear in the article. I suppose it would be $y(0)=a$, **can this initial condition plus that differential equation justify the claim stated in the title?**

ps: I have little background on elliptic functions so it would be nice if you provide an answer with reference to help me understand.

I wonder anyone can get the following function:
$$
y=b \mathrm{dn}(x,q) \text{  with  } q=1-a^2/b^2
$$
for this function defines an oscillation from $a$ to $b$. 
[image]

Comment: How did you arrive at the expression for $y''$?

Comment: @Dr.MV I expand the equation and take the derivative w.r.t x, cancel $\dot{y}$.

Comment: The factor of $2$ in the linear term in $y$ does not belong on the right-hand side.

Comment: Some possibly helpful intuition: You should get the equation $\ddot y=(a^2+b^2-2y^2)y$. This is the equation of a unit-mass particle under a spring-like force which is zero when $y=y^*=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)/2}$, and pulls the particle towards $y^*$ otherwise. Therefore, it is an oscillation. To find the range of the oscillation, find out when $\dot y=0$: this happens when $y=a$ or $y=b$.

Comment: @Rahul then this will result an elliptical integral?

Answer (score 1):

In the OP, there is an erroneous factor of $2$ appearing in the linear term on $y$.  To arrive at the coveted result, we begin with the ODE

$$\dot y^2(x)=-(y^2(x)-a^2)(y^2(x)-b^2) \tag 1$$

Differentiating both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $x$ yields

$$2\dot y\ddot y=-2y\dot y(y^2-a^2)-2y\dot y(y^2-b^2) \tag 2$$

Now, dividing both side of $(2)$ by $2\dot y$ we obtain

$$\ddot y=-y(y^2-a^2)-y(y^2-b^2)=-y(2y^2-a^2-b^2)=y(a^2+b^2)-2y^3$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I will plot your answer when I am on my computer.

Comment: With no offense, your answer just correct a typo of mine. Still, the jacobiCN seems not the right function. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

At $y=a$ and $y=b$ the derivative of $y$ is zero according to the diff eq.

For $a \lt y \lt b$, the second summand in the diff eq is negative while for $y \lt a$ or $b \lt y$ it is positive.

Assuming a real valued solution, $y\lt a$ is not possible because we would not get zero, i.e. the diff eq is not satisfied. Likewise $y \gt b$ is not possible. Two positive values cannot add up to zero.

But $a \lt y \lt b$ is possible and the derivative can then be either positive or negative (depending whether $y^{-1}(a)$ is smaller or larger than $y^{-1}(b)$). Hence, $y$ is monotonic.

Once $a$ or $b$ is reached, the only way to satisfy the diff eq is that $y$ remains constant.

Conclude by the definition of an oscillation.